# Write text over picture taken from SD card

Tags: android

Can anyone please refer any tutorial for writing text over images taken from SD card in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an EditText and Write into it and after writting you first convert it to Bitmap like

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mEditText.getDrawingCache());
Now you can add created image bmp to your original image like this

call like this : **Bitmap combined = combineImages(bgBitmap,bmp);**

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) { 

    int width = 0, height = 0;
    Bitmap cs;

    width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
    background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, matrix, null);

    return cs;
}
```

Comment: i wanted to drag the the text and later save it as a single image ..can u tell how to drag the text..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Surround the image with layout..then add the text view to the same layout